Problems with Named Entity Recognition in spaCy using German de_dep_news_trf Pipeline
I'm currently working on a project using spaCy with the German trained pipeline de_dep_news_trf.
Unfortunately, I'm having issues with named entity recognition (NER).
When I run a simple sentence like "Berlin ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland. Angela Merkel war die Bundeskanzlerin.", no entities are detected.
I've followed these steps to set up my Python environment (3.12)(Windows) in a PyCharm Community project:
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download de_dep_news_trf --timeout 600
pip install spacy[transformers]

Here is a snippet of my code:
import spacy


def process_text_with_spacy(text_to_process):
    doc = nlp(text_to_process)
    data = {
        "text": text_to_process,
        "sentences": []
    }
    for sent in doc.sents:
        process_sentence_data = {
            "sentence": sent.text,
            "entities": []
        }
        for ent in sent.ents:
            process_sentence_data["entities"].append({
                "text": ent.text,
                "start": ent.start_char,
                "end": ent.end_char,
                "label": ent.label_
            })
        data["sentences"].append(process_sentence_data)
    return data


nlp = spacy.load('de_dep_news_trf')

sample_text = "Berlin ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland. Angela Merkel war die Bundeskanzlerin."

processed_data = process_text_with_spacy(sample_text)

print("Text:", sample_text)
for sentence_data in processed_data["sentences"]:
    print("Sentence:", sentence_data["sentence"])
    print("Entities:", sentence_data["entities"])

Output:
Text: Berlin ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland. Angela Merkel war die Bundeskanzlerin.
Sentence: Berlin ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland.
Entities: []
Sentence: Angela Merkel war die Bundeskanzlerin.
Entities: []

When using de_core_news_lg, the output for each sentence is:
Text: Berlin ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland. Angela Merkel war die Bundeskanzlerin.
Sentence: Berlin ist die Hauptstadt von Deutschland.
Entities: [{'text': 'Berlin', 'start': 0, 'end': 6, 'label': 'LOC'}, {'text': 'Deutschland', 'start': 30, 'end': 41, 'label': 'LOC'}]
Sentence: Angela Merkel war die Bundeskanzlerin.
Entities: [{'text': 'Angela Merkel', 'start': 43, 'end': 56, 'label': 'PER'}]

However, when I use de_dep_news_trf, the results are empty.
Model de_dep_news_trf is selected based on "accuracy" from the SpaCy website.
Could someone explain why de_dep_news_trf does not return the same result? Is there a specific reason or setting that could cause this difference?
Thank you for your help!

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

what result do you expect? Show it in question (not in comments).

when I test it with English "en_core_web_sm" and "Berlin is capital city in Germany. Angela Merkel was Chancellor." then I get Entities: [{'text': 'Berlin', 'start': 0, 'end': 6, 'label': 'GPE'}, {'text': 'Germany', 'start': 26, 'end': 33, 'label': 'GPE'}] and Entities: [{'text': 'Angela Merkel', 'start': 35, 'end': 48, 'label': 'PERSON'}]. So it seems problem makes model.

when I use English model with German text then I get funny result: 'text': 'Hauptstadt von Deutschland', 'label': 'PERSON' :)

@furas Thank you for your feedback, I have added some details.

see documentation for de_dep_news_trf and components transformer, tagger, morphologizer, parser, lemmatizer, attribute_ruler - there is no ner for EntityRecognizer

@furas Correct! I'm sorry I didn't notice it myself. Thank you for the explanation.

I wonder if it possible to use only ner from other models - but it would need to load both models.

Problem is because this model doesn't have function to recognize entities.
See documentation for de_dep_news_trf - it has components transformer, tagger, morphologizer, parser, lemmatizer, attribute_ruler but no ner for EntityRecognizer
So it may need to use one of other models :

de_core_news_sm
de_core_news_md
de_core_news_lg

